# To convert a byte string to a matplotlib readable time

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was watching a python tutorial on youtube,  an episode is about using the byte string data to plot in matplotlib, but I don't have the access to the data used in the video, so I googled how to create one, but it feels kianda not right. I don't know if I found the right way to create a byte string data, the function used in the video fails to function in my program. 
here is the code:

```
def bytespdate2num(fmt,encoding='UTF-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

c = b'19970108'
a = bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')
print(a(c))
```

so what I got is that b = 729032.0

I don't think that I have thoroughly understood how the codes are utilized. Feel free to point out anywhere that I did wrong. thanks guys !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you show in the question, the code is correct. You input the string `c = b'19970108'` and get the output `729032.0`. This output signifies the first of august 1997 in the numeric datetime format that matplotlib uses.

You may convert back to `datetime` via

```
print(mdates.num2date(a(c)))
# this prints 1997-01-08 00:00:00+00:00
```

to see that it's working.

To plot the output you have essentially 3 options.

- Just using `plot` will of course show the numeric numbers (how would matplotlib know that it is supposed to plot a date?).

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  plt.plot( a(c), 1, marker="d")
  ```

  [image]
- **Using `plot_date()`**:

  ```
   plt.plot_date( a(c), 1, marker="d")
  ```

  [image]
- **Convert to `datetime` with `mdates.num2date`**:

  ```
  plt.plot( mdates.num2date(a(c)), 1, marker="d")
  ```

  [image]
- **Using a Locator and Formatter**:

  ```
  plt.plot( a(c), 1, marker="d")
  loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
  plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
  plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
  ```

  [image]
  This last method allows for the greatest flexibility, as you may also use other Locators and Formatters. See the [matplotlib.dates API](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) or the [official example](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html).

Comment: one more question here,  if I plot the data as the x-axis using pyplot, then it shows the number 729032.0 instead of the readable date. ╥﹏╥...